# PYTHON - How to get information after call to file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd

How to get information after call to file?
Example Input :
cmd > python file.py getme

How i can read the string 'getme'?

Comment: you need to elaborate more on what you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sys.argv` represents the command line arguments. Note the the first element (index 0) is the name of the script. So, in your case:\

```
import sys
arg = sys.argv[1] # this will contain "getme"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a lib to do that [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html?highlight=argparse#module-argparse), it is easy to use and offers a ruge ways to personalize your parameters.